# Dynamically initialize and call LoadLibrary from a TThread by demand only once

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dll, synchronization, delphi-7

I have a Delphi DLL, which needs to be called from my main UI application or worker threads.

I do not want to call LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary each time I call the DLL. But, I also don't want to load it in my application initialization section. because I might not use the DLL at all during the lifetime of the application.

So what I need is the first caller (thread or main UI) to initialize and load the DLL.
the DLL will be unloaded in the finalization section. I realize I need some synchronization. so I have used a critical section BUT I can't seem to make it work.

Only **one** thread should attempt and load the DLL.  if it fails other threads should not attempt to load the DLL again and again.

The synchronization is **not working** as expected!
Can someone suggest why?

**MCVE:**

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

const
  MyDLL = 'MyDLL.dll';

type
  TDLLProcessProc = function(A: Integer): Integer; stdcall;

var
  DLLProc: TDLLProcessProc = nil;
  DLLModule: HMODULE = 0;
  DLLInitialized: Boolean = False;
  DLLInitialized_OK: Boolean = False;
  CS: TRTLCriticalSection;

procedure InitDLLByFirstCall;
begin
  if DLLModule = 0 then
  begin
    if DLLInitialized then Exit;
    EnterCriticalSection(CS);
    try
      if DLLInitialized then Exit;
      DLLInitialized := True;
      DLLModule := LoadLibrary(MyDLL);
      if DLLModule = 0 then RaiseLastWin32Error;
      DLLProc := GetProcAddress(DLLModule, 'Process');
      if @DLLProc = nil then RaiseLastWin32Error;
      DLLInitialized_OK := True;
    finally
      LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
    end;
  end;
end;

function DLLProcess(A: Integer): Integer;
begin
  InitDLLByFirstCall;
  if not DLLInitialized_OK then
    raise Exception.Create('DLL was not initialized OK');
  Result := DLLProc(A);
end;

type
  TDLLThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FNum: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ANum: Integer);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor TDLLThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ANum: Integer);
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FNum := ANum;
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure TDLLThread.Execute;
var
  RetValue: Integer;
begin
  try
    RetValue := DLLProcess(FNum);
    Sleep(0);
    Writeln('TDLLThread Result=> ' + IntToStr(RetValue));
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln('TDLLThread Error: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  I: Integer;

begin
  InitializeCriticalSection(CS);
  try
    // First 10 thread always fail!  
    for I := 1 to 10 do
      TDLLThread.Create(False, I);
    Readln;

    for I := 1 to 10 do
      TDLLThread.Create(False, I);
    Readln;
  finally
    DeleteCriticalSection(CS);
  end;
end.
```

**DLL:**

```
library MyDLL;

uses
  Windows;

{$R *.res}        

function Process(A: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := A;
end;

exports
  Process;

begin
  IsMultiThread := True;
end.
```

Comment: What does "not working as expected" mean?  What is the expected behaviour?  What is the observed behaviour? How are they different?

Comment: Don't check for `DLLModule = 0`. Remove `DLLInitialized_OK`. Set `DLLInitialized` only once initialization has been completed. -1 for not really trying.

Comment: The CS can be destroyed before the threads execute.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, No its not.

Comment: It really can. You start your threads then you destroy the section. The ReadLn protects you but what I say can happen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, How cab that happen if there is a readLn there? The only mistake I have made is to use WriteLn in the thread context. Actually mghie nailed it as far as I have tested. but I don't understand why. and why my code did not work. funny you all said "code is fine" in my previous deleted question.

Comment: @mghie, It seem you are correct. but I don't understand why :/ and I don't think I deserve a -1. I really tried hard to figure out why its not working...

Comment: @user246408, The DLL code is in the  question! I gave a complete MCVE. I debugged for hours! what is wrong with SO???

Comment: @zig: I really think your question shows that you just added more variables and code instead of thinking through the problem. That makes for a question that isn't useful in general, and the second one for the same problem too, hence the -1. Why didn't you spend some more time on this? SO isn't a crowd-sourced debugging service. As for why it works with the changes I gave you - you really need to think through the double-checked locking and similar patterns (and understand them fully), or you need to stop writing multithreaded code. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @mghie, Thanks, but the problem in your solution was exactly what I was trying to avoid. if the first thread fails to load the DLL and an exception is raised (e.g. "The specified module could not be found" in LoadLibraray) all other threads will attempt to Load the Library again and again.

Comment: @zig: Then use an enumeration instead of the boolean, so you can encode the various states in it. But you need only one variable, that's key.

Comment: @mghie, I did not know that using only one variable is the **key** in such locking mechanism.

Comment: You would have known that if you'd made sure you understood the technique before coding it.

Comment: As for the ReadLn, what if it returns before the thread starts?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify your code in a way that the condition variable that is checked at the start of `InitDLLByFirstCall` is set only after all initialization has been completed. The DLL handle is therefore a bad choice.

Second you need to use the same condition variable outside and inside of the critical section - if you use `DLLInitialized` for that, then there is not really a use for either `DLLInitialized_OK` nor `DLLModule`.

And to make things easier to reason about you should try to get away with the minimum number of variables. Something like the following should work:

```
var
  DLLProc: TDLLProcessProc = nil;
  DLLInitialized: Boolean = False;
  CS: TRTLCriticalSection;

procedure InitDLLByFirstCall;
var
  DLLModule: HMODULE;
begin
  if DLLInitialized then
    Exit;

  EnterCriticalSection(CS);
  try
    if not DLLInitialized then
    try
      DLLModule := LoadLibrary(MyDLL);
      Win32Check(DLLModule <> 0);

      DLLProc := GetProcAddress(DLLModule, 'Process');
      Win32Check(Assigned(DLLProc));
    finally
      DLLInitialized := True;
    end;
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
  end;
end;

function DLLProcess(A: Integer): Integer;
begin
  InitDLLByFirstCall;
  if @DLLProc = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('DLL was not initialized OK');
  Result := DLLProc(A);
end;
```

If you don't want to check for the function address inside of `DLLProcess` then you could also use an integer or enumeration for the `DLLInitialized` variable, with different values for *not initialized*, *failed* and *success*.

Comment: Can I hold the DLLModule global like I did for later use with FreeLibrary?

Comment: @zig: You can, but there is no real use if the module remains loaded until program shutdown. Windows will clean things up after process termination anyway.

Comment: Thanks @mghie, I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: `Win32Check(DLLModule <> 0)` and `Win32Check(@DLLProc <> nil)` is a nice idiom to further simplify this well written code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed, that makes it easier to read. Thanks for the suggestion, incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your double checked locking implemented incorrectly. You assign to `DLLModule` before assigning to `DLLProc`. So `DLLModule` can be non-zero whilst `DLLProc` is still null.

The variable that you test outside the lock must be modified after all the initialization is complete.

The pattern is like this:

```
if not Initialised then begin
  Lock.Enter;
  if not Initialised then begin
    // Do initialisation
    Initialised := True; // after initialisation complete
  end;
  Lock.Leave;
end;
```

Remember that double checked locking, as implemented here, only works because of the strong x86 memory model. If you ever move this code onto hardware with a weak memory model, it won't work as implemented. You'd need to implement barriers. Possible to do, but not entirely trivial.

Double checked locking is pointless here though. Remove it and protect everything with a single critical section. You are spinning up a thread, a very expensive task. The potential contention on a critical section is negligible.

Comment: "Use a critical section" But I do use a critical section.

Comment: Oh, never mind, do it your way, with all the needless complexity

Comment: So you suggest to block every call, every time with a critical section when I call DLLProcess (even from main UI)? If yes this is how I actually started but I thought It would be a very bad idea.

Comment: No. Block once when you start the thread. Anyway, you've made your mind up it seems. It looks like you are more interested in being spoon fed code that you don't understand than actually understanding the issues. There's no reward for me in spoon feeding. I'll help you try to understand if you actually want that.

Comment: "Anyway, you've made your mind up it seems" - mghie gave me an answer that exactly answered my question, and the code helped me understand my mistakes. I will dig deeper to try and fully understand the issue. seems like you are aggravated by this fact "Oh, never mind, do it your way". I am very thankful to you and your contribution to SO. and yes I really want to understand. I am doing my best to learn this issue but it's not trivial to me.

Comment: When you say "No. Block once when you start the thread" - that does not make any sense to me, sorry for being dumb.

Comment: It seems to me that you are searching out needless complexity. Usually people do that when they don't understand what they are doing.

Comment: You've accepted the other answer. You have determined that double checked is the solution. That's fine. I wouldn't do it that way. But you can.